# IAM policy to allow user to launch EC2 with restrictions

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am working on an IAM policy that allows the IAM user to only launch the instance `"ami-0885b1f6bd170450c"` in the region `"us-east-1"` with the EBS volume of no more than `20gb` . I am not sure what mistake I am making after reviewing the policy only `RunInstances` is shown.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-0885b1f6bd170450c",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
                },
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Region": "us-east-1"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EC2CreateVolume",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:CreateVolume",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NumericLessThanEquals": {
                    "ec2:VolumeSize": "20"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the decrypted error message I got while launching

```
{
  "allowed": false,
  "explicitDeny": false,
  "matchedStatements": {
    "items": []
  },
  "failures": {
    "items": []
  },
  "context": {
    "principal": {
      "id": "AIDAYGEGJ25OKBMOEFSLA",
      "name": "some-user",
      "arn": "arn:aws:iam::562922379100:user/some-user"
    },
    "action": "ec2:RunInstances",
    "resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:562922379100:instance/*",
    "conditions": {
      "items": [
        {
          "key": "ec2:MetadataHttpPutResponseHopLimit",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "1"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:InstanceMarketType",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "on-demand"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:Resource",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "instance/*"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:Account",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "562922379100"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:AvailabilityZone",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "us-east-1e"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:ebsOptimized",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "false"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:IsLaunchTemplateResource",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "false"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:InstanceType",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "t2.micro"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:RootDeviceType",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "ebs"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:Region",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "us-east-1"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:MetadataHttpEndpoint",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "enabled"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:Service",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "ec2"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:InstanceID",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "*"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:MetadataHttpTokens",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "optional"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:Type",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "instance"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:Tenancy",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "default"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:Region",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "us-east-1"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:ARN",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:562922379100:instance/*"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ec2:TerminateInstances`, `ec2:StopInstances` & `ec2:StartInstances` operate on the instance (`arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::instance/*`) not the image/AMI (`arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-0885b1f6bd170450c`).

I also think you will have issues launching instances with just this policy as your missing some required resources.

Here is an AWS sample for [restricting launching ec2 instance by AMI and TAG](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restrict-launch-tagged-ami/) you might be able to adapt.

Comment: Yes !! even that didn't work. I allowed all instances terminate,stop and start but still couldn't launch the instance.